# Angular Js get checked checkox elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have html code

```
            <tr ng-repeat="fee in Fees">
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="input-fee" ng-model="item"></td>  
                <td>{{fee.name}}</td>
            </tr>
```

In jquery we can get all checked elements by doing this

```
var $Fees = this.$el.find('input.input-fee:checked');
```

How can we get this in angular , I tried this

```
var $Fees = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('input.input-fee:checked'));
```

it is not returning checked item object

Comment: Idk what `item` is, but that's the `ngModel` of each checkbox - use the data for this. Loop your `Fees` collections and find which ones are checked (actually bind this to an object property, such as `fee.checked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` looks for elements with the specified class name and you are trying to filter with an element selector `input` with a class selector `input-fee` which will never work.

Just try

```
angular.element('input.input-fee:checked');
```

Comment: Working perfect Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="fee in Fees">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="input-fee" ng-model="fee.isChecked"></td>  
    <td>{{fee.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Take a boolean isChecked and make it true or false accordingly.